# MongoDB as a lock with WriteConcern Majority and ReadConcern Linearizable

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I got one place in my application where I want to use Mongo (3.6) as a lock of multiple threads (on different servers). Essentially something like "if one thread started work, other threads should see it through mongo and dont start the same work in parallel".

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-linearizable/)  I learned

> Combined with "majority" write concern, "linearizable" read concern enables multiple threads to perform reads and writes on a single document as if a single thread performed these operations in real time;

So this sounded good to me, I insert a certain document if one thread starts work, and other threads check if such document already exists and dont start if so, but it does not work for my case.

I prepared two tests - one non-parallel that successfully blocks the second thread - but the parallel test fails and I get two of these `RebuildLog` documents.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace FindOneAndUpdateTests
{
    public class FindOneAndUpdateTests
    {
        private static IMongoDatabase GetDatabase()
        {
            var dbName = "test";
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:45022");

            return client.GetDatabase(dbName);
        }

        private IMongoCollection<RebuildLog> GetCollection()
        {
            return GetDatabase().GetCollection<RebuildLog>("RebuildLog");
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task FindOneAndUpdate_NotParallel_Test()
        {
            var dlpId = Guid.NewGuid();

            var first = await FindOneAndUpdateMethod(dlpId);
            var second = await FindOneAndUpdateMethod(dlpId);

            first.Should().BeFalse();
            second.Should().BeTrue();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task FindOneAndUpdate_Parallel_Test()
        {
            var dlpId = Guid.NewGuid();

            var taskFirst = FindOneAndUpdateMethod(dlpId);
            var taskSecond = FindOneAndUpdateMethod(dlpId);

            var first = await taskFirst;
            var second = await taskSecond;

            first.Should().BeFalse();
            second.Should().BeTrue();
        }

        private async Task<bool> FindOneAndUpdateMethod(Guid dlpId)
        {
            var mongoCollection = GetCollection();

            var filterBuilder = Builders<RebuildLog>.Filter;
            var filter = filterBuilder.Where(w => w.DlpId == dlpId);

            var creator = Builders<RebuildLog>.Update
                .SetOnInsert(w => w.DlpId, dlpId)
                .SetOnInsert(w => w.ChangeDate, DateTime.UtcNow)
                .SetOnInsert(w => w.BuildDate, DateTime.UtcNow)
                .SetOnInsert(w => w.Id, Guid.NewGuid());

            var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<RebuildLog>
            {
                IsUpsert = true,
                ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before
            };

            var result = await mongoCollection
                .WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.WMajority)
                .WithReadConcern(ReadConcern.Linearizable)
                .FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, creator, options);

            return result != null;
        }
    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class RebuildLog
    {
        public RebuildLog()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string ChangeUser { get; set; }
        public Guid DlpId { get; set; }
        public string Portal { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BuildDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that my idea with the atomic handcrafted GetOrInsert (see the FindOneAndUpdate with IsUpsert) breaks the constraint of "on a single document" in the documentation. Any idea to fix this or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting. May be you have no unique index on DlpId? That's why mongo decides that sequential execution of these operations is not necessary because in your case it's no write-then-read pattern (as it pointed in "Client Sessions and Causal Consistency Guarantees"). It is update-or-create two times concurrently.
What about this? :

```
public class SyncDocument 
{
    // ...
    [BsonElement("locked"), BsonDefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
}
```

In client code:

```
var filter = Builders<SyncDocument>.Filter.Eq(d => d.Locked, false);
var update = Builders<SyncDocument>.Update.Set(d => d.Locked, true);
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
if (result.ModifiedCount == 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("Lock acquired");
}
```

Document with Locked field should be created before applications startup (if it is applicable for your task).